# I have encountered a problem in solving this number theory problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

If A is the sum of the digits of $4444^{4444}$ and B is the sum of the digits of A then find, the sum of the digits of B.

I tried using mod(10), Fermat's Theorem alongside Euler's Totient Function but I am not able to make it through, Please help with this question.

Comment: Hint. $4444^{4444}\equiv A\equiv B\pmod9$.

Comment: The punchline is that $4444^{4444}$ has fewer than $5000\cdot \log_{10}(10000)=25000$ digits (*we could be more specific if it mattered, but it doesn't matter, and it is obvious that $4444\cdot \log_{10}(4444)$ is smaller than even this*) and so has digit sum fewer than $9\cdot 25000$.  The sum of the digits of this result is capped by a certain amount.  The sum of the digits of that is capped by a certain result.... to the point of us having only one possibility that is the correct value mod9